# How to Bind a Readonly var to the Data Of a ListModel in QML?

Tags: qt, design-patterns, qml, dynamic-data, listmodel

#### Brief

Is it possible to create a `readonly property var` bound to the data inside the `ListElement` values of a `ListModel`?

(Or is there some equivalent route to get a structured `readonly` object containing this data without the write exposure of a `readonly property ListModel`'s `get(...)` function?)

---

#### Background / Full-Version

I'm working with a data model code in `qml`.  This installed project makes heavy use of a `pragma Singleton` front-end / `QtObject` back-end pattern, in which the data in the front-end is `readonly`, the backend is conditionally loaded via a `Loader` w/ `source` assigned via a `switch` conditional, and where partner runtime projects instead use `function` calls to order the backend to change data (when necessary).  This is done to assist in obfuscating whether the backend is real data read in from hardware, or mocked up data set by the partner project with the runtime code.  Another upside is the ability to dynamically switch from hardware inputs to software mockups at runtime.

The basic pattern is:

> SomeFeatureFrontEnd.qml

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
   id: someFeatureFrontEnd

   readonly property string _backend: "fake"
   readonly property double fraction: _backend.item.fraction
   readonly property int counter: _backend.item.counter

   //... etc ...

   function setFraction(value) { _backend.item.setFraction(value) }

   function incrementCounter() { _backend.item.incrementCounter() }

   function decrementCounter() { _backend.item.decrementCounter() }

   //... etc ...

    _backend: Loader {
        id: _backend
        source: {
            switch(backend) {
                case "fake":
                default:
                   return "backends/SomeFeatureBackendFake.qml"
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

> backends/SomeFeatureBackendApi.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

//This is just an interface for the derived backend children 
//  not actually instantiation.
QtObject {
   property double fraction
   property int counter

   //... etc ...

   function setFraction(value) { }

   function incrementCounter() { }

   function decrementCounter() { }

   //... etc ...
}
```

> backends/SomeFeatureBackendFake.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

SomeFeatureBackendApi {
   fraction: 1.0
   counter: 0

   //... etc ...

   function setFraction(value) { fraction = value }

   function incrementCounter() { counter++ }

   function decrementCounter() { counter-- }

   //... etc ...
}
```

Now within that general strategy I've encountered a sort of dilemma in that I would like to add some dynamically allocated structured data in the same manner as `counter` and `fraction` above.  A seemingly intuitive fit for this is seemingly `ListModel` as it supports structured, modifiable data.

A few details about the ListModel:

- Integer indexing.
- `ListElement` data is all basic types `real` / `double`

Or if it's more convenient here's an example:

> ThingList.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListModel {
   //Initializer code to dynamically initialize w/ an
   //arbitrary number of ThingEntry instances...
}
```

> ThingEntry.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListElement {
   property double profileValue
   property int profileScore
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions on the obfuscated code snippets above.

Now recapping the question / dilemma per the brief, regarding the use of this `ListModel` with my backend/frontend pattern:

Per my understanding `readonly property ListModel structuredStuff` is still modifiable via `structuredStuff.get()` calls, right?  I don't want that...  I want whatever is on the frontend to be `readonly` for the reasons discussed above.

How do I conveniently and efficiently get a `readonly` representation that's `var`-like in the front-end, based upon the non-readonly `property ListModel` in the backend?

Comment: I am not quite sure how you want to use the model or its elements. E.g. would that be a model in the front end or just accessed via functions? I.e. if a property could be made constant and not just read-only, how would you imagine accessing its content?

Comment: Not as far as I know. But why do you need them to be readonly? You could hide them instead.

Comment: The reason I want a `varlist` (or some equivalent) is that it simplifies populating structures dependent on `modelData`.  Currently I'm doing precisely what you suggest -- hiding it, but it's kind of a pain because I have to include functions to get the length of my backend `ListModel` (to give `count` to the dependent widget such as `Repeater`), and then for each individual attribute call my `get...(...)` helper methods to access the attributes to populate each child of the widget (i.e. the repeater children).  I'd like the convenience of `ListModel` w/out the exposed writability.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a framework for this problem based on qml.
the basic problem is the listmodel must contain direct data, but not object,
in my framework, the listmodel can contain any qt object, which is support data binding, i.e. the listmodel data can binding to other qt data/var.